# What Material Design library could this be coming from?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-design

I am trying to emulate the css styling for this type of Material Design-based web application:

[image]

I have looked through Materialize CSS and MUI and I do not think its either of those, but I feel overwhelmed as to the amount of Material Design libraries out there that could be creating this type of design, if indeed this was created with a css framework.

Does anyone more experienced with me have an idea what Material Design CSS framework has gone into this elegant design you see above? If any at all, or can this be easily pulled off with just straight css?

The icon is simple, its a Material Design icon and I have integrated that already, but this grid looking card style list seems to be inside some type of iframe view. So you can scroll through these cards inside an iframe type of design inside the screen and as you can see when you hover over a card, it highlights to this teal color.

I tried MUI panel which has only accomplished this:

[image]

My code for this looks like so:

```
class LocationList extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchLocations();
  }

  renderLocation() {
    return this.props.locations.map(location => {
      return (
        <div className="mui-panel" key={location.id}>
          <div className="">
            <div className="">
              <h1>
                {location.name}
                {location.airport_code}
              </h1>
              <MaterialIcon icon="airplanemode_active" />
              <p>{location.description}</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div className="">{this.renderLocation()}</div>;
  }
}
```

Or even if you can share how you would identify it yourself.

Thank you for any time you can spare in assisting me.

Comment: Have you deploy your code on any server? If yes then please share the link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take what you have and use a grid system to place the panels side-by-side like they did. Other than that the only differences that I notice are fonts, placement, left border width and color, and hover color. Those can all be accomplished with CSS I'm pretty sure. If there is a framework that those panels came from, I have not seen it before. I think you can do most of that yourself with a fairly small amount of trouble. You can look at page source to possibly identify the framework if there is one. If there are any unique looking class name, etc. you can do a search for those and see if there's a framework that uses those names.